# Is there a way to get number of events and total per included variable in logistic regression in R?

Tags: r, events, logistic-regression

I am using the following code to do multivariable logistic regression in R on gigantic dataset

```
mylogit <- glm( MAG ~  factor(Gender) + age +
                factor(RaceCaucasian)+
                factor(Diabetes)+
                factor(Dialysis)+
                 BMI, family=binomial); summary(mylogit)
```

Is there a way to get number of events and total per included categorical variables in logistic regression in R?

Comment: is this the sort of thing you want: `with(mylogit$data, ftable(Gender, RaceCaucasian, Diabetes, Dialysis, MAG))`

Comment: Thanks for your input. It gave complex results that need to be polished as I need all events (MAG )  in diabetes, then all events in dialysis..etc among the regression data (that usually delete any row with missing data)

Comment: okay, I'm unsyre what is required. is it only cross tables oyu want: `with(mylogit$data, table(Dialysis, MAG))` etc. If not can you construct a small example say using `glm(am ~ factor(cyl) + factor(gear), mtcars, family=binomial)` and then show the expected outcome for that small dataset & model. Thanks